# How to repeat an array n times using JSX

Tags: reactjs, api

I am using React/JSX in my app.

**i need to reapet data from API n times in first time**. if i click on button it reapet more n times. another click-> another n times reapet and over and over.
the api give me 1 results every time. i can define results if it necessary

my code:

```
 const n=2;

 arr:[];


handleClick(){
//i need the code to increase n another 2 times
}



//the array here without the code to fill api data. not relevant
 this.state.arr.map((d,key)=>
<span>age: {d.age} </span>


<button onClick={this.handleClick} >
```

Expected result in first results:

age:20

age:24

after click on button:

age:20

age:24

age:48

age:19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on where your API call is, but in order to update the array, you should be using `this.setState` in your `handleClick`

```
handleClick() {
  this.setState({
    arr: this.state.arr.concat(newContentArray)
  })
}
```

No clue how your obtaining the data, but that's the general principle. Take your existing `this.state.arr` and `concat` the array with the new data.

Be sure to use `bind` or an arrow function on your `button` event handler.